# Getting ValueError because of 4D numpy array? Sklearn and nilearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, nilearn

I'm trying to load in some MRI grey matter map images as numpy arrays so they can be processed in sklearn. My code imports them and loads them using NiftiMasker (NiftiMasker applies a mask to the image to extract a time series, which is what I believe is the 4th dimension in the numpy array that is causing the error). I'm getting a ValueError when I try to run this code because for some reason the data is being loaded in as a 4D numpy array when all I need is a 3D array. Is there a way to reduce the dimensions of the array or some other way to solve this error? Here is code:

```
import nibabel
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nilearn.input_data import NiftiMasker
import pandas as pd
import pdb
import os

def getgm(path):
    """Gets the subject number on the folder that contains the scans
     and appends them on a list called dirnames"""  
    gmnames = []
    paths = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            gmnames.append(filename)
    for gmname in gmnames:
        path = os.path.join('Z:\Projects\MTS_Project\spm\dataset', gmname)
        paths.append(path)
    return paths
print(getgm('Z:\Projects\MTS_Project\spm\dataset'))

#loads MTSData as a list of paths
MTS_data = getgm('Z:\Projects\MTS_Project\spm\dataset')
print(MTS_data[0])

#loads side data from mtsdata.csv
fields = ['ID', 'SIDE']
csv = pd.read_csv('mtsdata.csv', skipinitialspace = True, usecols = fields)
age = csv.SIDE

nifti_masker = NiftiMasker(standardize = False, smoothing_fwhm=2, verbose=1)

gm_maps_masked = []

for data in MTS_data:
    gm_maps_masked.append(nifti_masker.fit_transform(data))


#nifti_masker.fit(MTS_data)
#gm_maps_masked = nifti_masker.transform(MTS_data)
#print(gm_maps_masked)




#n_features = gm_maps_masked.shape
#print(n_features)



print("ANOVA + SVR")
# Define the prediction function to be used.
# Here we use a Support Vector Classification, with a linear kernel
from sklearn.svm import SVR
svr = SVR(kernel='linear')

# Dimension reduction
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold, SelectKBest, \
        f_regression

# Remove features with too low between-subject variance
variance_threshold = VarianceThreshold(threshold=1)

# Here we use a classical univariate feature selection based on F-test,
# namely Anova.
feature_selection = SelectKBest(f_regression, k=2000)

# We have our predictor (SVR), our feature selection (SelectKBest), and now,
# we can plug them together in a *pipeline* that performs the two operations
# successively:
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
anova_svr = Pipeline([
            ('variance_threshold', variance_threshold),
            ('anova', feature_selection),
            ('svr', svr)])


### Fit and predict
for gmmap in gm_maps_masked:
    anova_svr.fit(gm_maps_masked,age)
pdb.set_trace()
age_pred = anova_svr.predict(gm_maps_masked)
```

Here is error and traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "learn.py", line 81, in <module>
    anova_svr.fit(gm_maps_masked,age)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 248, in fit
    Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 213, in _fit
    **fit_params_steps[name])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py", line 362, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 581, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 520, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\variance_threshold.py", line 64, in fit
    X = check_array(X, ('csr', 'csc'), dtype=np.float64)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4518515) into shape (1)
```

Comment: One of the dimensions might be a number of samples, while the three other are respectively rgb features. You sure you need to reduce dimension?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure if I need to reduce dimensions, but I don't believe the last dimension holds any useful information and it seems to be causing the problem. I believe the last dimension is part of the time-series which I do not need for this data set.

Comment: The error occurs deep in the `fit` method, so it's hard to trace what is going on.  But the `(1,)` shape suggests that the array in question is an object dtype array wrapping some non-array object. I would check the shape and dtype of  `gm_maps_masked` and make sure it conforms to the documentation.

Comment: Why do you iterate on `gm_maps_masked`, but pass the whole array to `fit` rather than `gmmap`?